# Overloading operator + starting from += for vector class in C++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, standard-library

I know there are plenty of discussions about this topic, [like this famous one (see sbi's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading). My goal is to overload the operator + for two vectors, starting from the operator +=, as explained in the linked famous question.

The following code snippet is quite **classical**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
class vector{
private:
    T* elem;
    std::size_t _size;
public:
    vector(const std::size_t size) : elem{new T[size]}, _size{size} {}
    ~vector(){ delete[] elem;}
    std::size_t size() const { return _size;}
    T& operator[](std::size_t i){ return elem[i];}
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const{ return elem[i];}
    vector& operator+=(const vector& b) ;
    vector& operator=(vector b);
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vector<T>& v) {
  for (auto i = 0u; i < v.size(); ++i)
    os << "v[" << i << "] = " << v[i] << std::endl;
  return os;
}

template <typename T>
vector<T>& vector<T>::operator+=(const vector<T>& b) {
    for (std::size_t i =0;i<_size;++i){
        elem[i]+=b[i];
    }
    return *this; 
}

template <typename T>
vector<T> operator+(vector<T> a,const vector<T>& b){
    a+=b;
    return a;
}



template <typename T>
vector<T>& vector<T>::operator=(vector<T> b){
    std::swap(*this,b);
    return *this;
}






int main(){


    vector<double> v{10};
    vector<double> w{10};
    for (auto i=0u;i<v.size();++i){
        v[i] = i;
        w[i]  = i*i;
    }

    v+=w;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;


    vector<double> v1{10};
    v1 = w + v;
    std::cout << v1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After I compile, I obtain several warnings, and when I execute I obtain the following error

`free(): double free detected in tcache 2 Aborted (core dumped)`

and I can't undertand neither where it happens, nor how to fix it. I'm trying to  stick as much as I can to the suggestions in the linked topic, but there's some bug in my overloading procedure, and I can't spot where/why.

Comment: You have a rule of three violation.  You need a copy constructor as the default does a shallow copy, meaning two vectors will share the same buffer and one will delete it from the other.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ups, I didn't face this topic yet. I'm trying to write this +operator without knowing what a shallow copy is

Comment: Well, you have to know how to properly copy objects, in order to implement the operator overload. This is not optional. It is mandatory.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible to overload the "+" operator "(n my case for my vector class) without knowing how to copy objects. Could you just confirm that my +=operator is well overloaded? I mean, it just returns a reference, so it should be okay, right? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: That part is ok. However if `b`'s size is smaller than `this`'s size, this operator overload will obviously result in undefined behavior and garbage results.

Comment: Your `operator +=` is not correct.  What happens if the vector you are adding to is bigger then the one you are adding from?

Comment: Of course such an operation must be not defined. My idea was to throw an exception for the moment (it's the only thing about error handling that we saw), could it be okay with this adustment? @NathanOliver

I'm sorry if this is too low level, but I've just began my c++ course and I was trying to go further with the vector class we saw at lecture

Comment: Could this be okay? @SamVarshavchik